# Send same telemetry data to two different serial ports?

Tags: serial, teensy

I'm using a Teensy 3.5 to control a wall-following robot. The robot sends telemetry to my PC via two independent ports - Serial1 & Serial.  Serial is the normal USB port, used when I direct-connect to the robot for troubleshooting, etc. Serial1 is tied to an HC-05 Bluetooth transceiver and it is used to acquire telemetry remotely.

I have to send telemetry to both ports, because I never know which (or either, or both) port(s) are actually active at any one time, so I wind up with lines like the following all over my code:

```
Serial.printf("\nChecking for MPU6050 IMU at I2C Addr 0x%x\n", MPU6050_I2C_ADDR);
Serial1.printf("\nChecking for MPU6050 IMU at I2C Addr 0x%x\n", MPU6050_I2C_ADDR);
```

needless to say this gets old after a while, and is error prone (I might edit one line and forget to copy/paste it to the other one).  What I would really like to do is create a function that would accept a printf-style string and send it to both ports, but I'm having trouble figuring out how to do that.

I have tried playing around with strcpy and strcat without much success:

```
  char quotestr[] = "\"";
  char hellostr[] = "hello";
  char instr[] = "%s\n, hellostr";
  char deststr[40];
  memset(deststr, 0, sizeof(deststr));
  strcat(deststr, quotestr);
  strcat(deststr, instr);
  strcat(deststr, quotestr);
  Serial.printf("quotestr = %s\n", quotestr);
  Serial.printf("instr = %s\n", instr);
  Serial.printf("deststr = %s\n", deststr);
  Serial.printf(deststr);
```

But the output is wrong because the '\n' gets interpreted as a CRLF pair even though it is in a string with double-quotes.

```
quotestr = "
instr = %s
, hellostr
deststr = "%s
, hellostr"
"
, hellostr"
```

It seems like there ought to be a way to do this easily, but I can't figure it out.  Any help would be appreciated.

TIA,

Frank

Comment: The `\n` gets interpreted as a newline, just as it is normal for Linux based OS. I would say it is doing exactly what you told it to do. Where are you looking at this? Why is this a problem? And have you thought about using `sprintf()` to build the string into a char array, which you can then print on both Serial interfaces?

Comment: if you don't want a new line, then remove the \n from the string

Comment: Using `\\n` instead of `\n` should do the trick.

Answer (score 4):

you can write a simple T output using the base class `Print`. The standard Arduino `Print` class doesn't have `printf` but from your code it looks like the Teense core has `printf` in `Print`.

```
class TeePrint: public Print {

  Print &out1;
  Print &out2;

public:

  TeePrint(Print &_out1, Print &_out2) : out1(_out1), out2(_out2) {}

  virtual size_t write(uint8_t b) {
    out1.write(b);
    out2.write(b);
    return 1;
  }

};

TeePrint log(Serial, Serial1);

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  Serial1.begin(9600);

  log.printf("abcd %d %s", 1234, "xyz");
}

void loop() {

}
```

Comment: Thanks - your TeePrint class is very elegant.  One minor nit - it refused to compile for T3.2 because 'log' was declared in math.h.  When I changed from 'log' to 'myTee', everything worked fine

Answer (score 0):

The simplest method is a variadic macro:

```cpp
#define PRINTF(...) do { Serial.printf(__VA_ARGS__); Serial1.printf(__VA_ARGS__); } while(0)
```

Then you can just use `PRINTF("foo: %d", bar);` and it will expand it out to the two printfs for you.

Comment: This will fail on `if (bar) PRINTF("foo: %d", bar);`. That's why people use the `do {...} while (0)` idiom.

Comment: @EdgarBonet I did consider adding the `{}` but didn't bother. I should have. I have now. The do and while aren't needed.

Comment: The `do` and `while (0)` are needed for `if (bar) PRINTF(...); else ...` to work as expected.

Comment: @EdgarBonet No, you only need the {} for that.

Comment: That's incorrect. Try it!

Comment: Wouldn't that render the output string twice? Might make a huge difference if the user wants to print complicated stuff especially if floats are involved.

Comment: @EdgarBonet I do, regularly. I have never used, nor even seen, the do while construct.

Comment: @luni64 yes it would, but on a teensy it won't be noticeable as they are so much faster than an Arduino.

Comment: Without the `do` and `while (0)`, `if (bar) PRINTF(...); else ...` gives `error: ‘else’ without a previous ‘if’`. Try it, seriously! The `do {…} while (0)` construct is the standard fix for this problem, and it is [a very common idiom](https://www.google.com/search?q=C+macro+do+while+0).

Comment: @EdgarBonet Ah, that'll be the fact that you added a ; after the macro when you used it. Don't do that?

Comment: If you remember to _not_ add a trailing semicolon after the macro, then it works. But that is confusing, as the macro looks superficially like a function, yet it has to be used with a different syntax. Would you refrain to add a semicolon after `getc()` because [it may be implemented as a macro](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getc.3p.html)?

Comment: @EdgarBonet The fact it's all in capitals is a dead giveaway that it's a macro. That's the convention. Sure, if you want to add a do while around it then do (while). It's not in my coding style, so I don't. I write my macro names in all caps so I remember they're macros, and don't need a ; after them. Everyone's coding style is unique.

Comment: “Everyone's coding style is unique” is not an excuse for being confusing. You fell in your own trap, as you accidentally added a semicolon in the first two versions of this answer. Imagine how easily someone else using a macro defined by you may fall in this trap.

Comment: @EdgarBonet If it'll shut you up I'll add it. I still don't use it personally though.